# How do I import/include MATLAB functions?

Tags: file, function, matlab, import, include

I have some MATLAB functions defined in .m files and I'd like to import them into MATLAB (as in I'd like to be able to call them as I do a built-in function). How can I do this?

Comment: Related: [How to use the MATLAB search path](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2129646/52738)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the path. See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html).

Answer (score 33):

If the folder just contains functions then adding the folders to the [path](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/path.html) at the start of the script will suffice.

```
addpath('../folder_x/');
addpath('../folder_y/');
```

If they are Packages, folders starting with a '+' then they also need to be imported.

```
import package_x.*
import package_y.*
```

You need to [add the package folders parent to the search path](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_env/files-and-folders-that-matlab-accesses.html).

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to put them in your ~/matlab on unix.

I'm not sure which directory matlab looks in for windows, but you should be able to figure it out by executing `userpath` from the matlab command line.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution for Windows

Go to File --> Set Path and add the folder containing the functions as Matlab files. (At least for Matlab 2007b on Vista)

Comment: Vista is a bit older. Do you happen to know whether it still works this way?