# Strange error in using matlab program ==> Too many input argument

Tags: matlab, input

We have very strange error that I don't know why:
   This code run with my laptop and is correct but It doesn't work with another
   laptop(has the same matlab version) with this error TOO MANY INPUT ARGUMENT 
   In Line 10!

```
clear
syms b c d;
E=29000; I=240/144;
mab=2*E*I*(b)/18;
mba=2*E*I*(2*b)/18;
mbc=2*E*I*(2*b+c)/12-24;
mcb=2*E*I*(b+2*c)/12+24;
mbd=2*E*I*(2*b+d-3*.6/144)/12;
mdb=2*E*I*(b+2*d-3*.6/144)/12;
[tetb tetc tetd]=solve(mcb==0,mba+mbc+mbd==0,mdb==0,b,c,d)
c=tetc;
b=tetb;
d=tetd;
eval(mab)
```

Comment: Run `which solve` on both computers to check if the same functions are used.

Comment: @Nemesis Thanks so much the solution is, but how can I change the path of solve .m?

Answer (score 0):

Use `which solve` to check which function is called. Since they differ in your case (see comments), you can use the method given for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153323/executing-a-file-or-calling-a-function-whose-file-is-placed-in-another-folder-wi) to exactly specify the path for a function to use. See `addpath` and `rmpath` there.