# Scilab several custom functions

Tags: matlab, scilab

I have several functions in different .sci files. Also, these files are in different directories. These functions are used by a main program. 
With old `Scilab` versions I have used `getf(...)` to load all the functions (one `getf(...)` per function, of course) and `getf(...)` to load the main program too.

The questions are:

- How do I load the main program and all the functions into `Scilab`'s new version/environment?
- What about Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sylvestre points out in Scilab you call `exec()` with the filename of your module.

In Matlab it's not a directly comparable operation (this is one of the areas they diverge): you place each external function in a file whose filename matches the function name then put that file in the path: when you call the function Matlab searches the path for matching files. This does mean you can only have one function per file but if you want C-style `#include` functionality there are various methods on [this thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/160868).

For your purposes - multiple directories - you might want to add each relevant directory to the path in your startup.m file. See also [How to use the MATLAB search path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129646/how-to-use-the-matlab-search-path).

Answer (score 2):

*exec* replaces *gef*:
http://help.scilab.org/docs/current/en_US/exec.html

But if you are starting to write a Scilab module (extension), you should have a look to the toolbox skeleton provided with Scilab.